# lme4::nlmer, Error in devfun(rho$pp$theta) : Downdated VtV is not positive definite

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, nonlinear-optimization

I have simulated some data in my code and want to fit a non-linear mixed model to using lme4::nlmer, however I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in devfun(rho$pp$theta) : Downdated VtV is not positive definite
```

My code is:

```
library(nlme)
library(ggplot2)
library(lme4)
library(gridExtra)
library(MASS)

nparams <- c("delta1", "delta2", "delta3", "Time")
fpl1 <- deriv(as.formula(paste0("~((delta1) * exp(Time - (delta2) )) / (1 + exp((Time - (delta2)) / (delta3)))")), c("delta1", "delta2", "delta3"), function.arg = nparams, envir=environment())

createDataset <- function(nGroups, totalDaysMeasured, d1, d2, d3) {
  residualSD <- 0.939921
  nIndividuals <- 600
  D <- rbind(c(51.88633, -1.0498620, -0.05460614), c(-1.0498620, 15.8465000, -0.04587260), c(-0.05460614, -0.04587260, 0.01362791))
  random_effects <- mvrnorm(n = nIndividuals, mu = rep(0, 3), Sigma = D)
  nDays <- totalDaysMeasured
  groups <- rep(paste0("g",1:nGroups),each=3)
  
  days = seq(0, 25, length.out = totalDaysMeasured)
  data <- data.frame(Day = rep(days,each=nIndividuals),
                     Group = rep(groups,nDays),
                     Individual = rep(1:nIndividuals,nDays))
  
  asymp.RNoiseByIndividual1 <- random_effects[, 1]
  asymp.RNoiseByIndividual2 <- random_effects[, 2] 
  asymp.RNoiseByIndividual3 <- random_effects[, 3] 
  data$X <- with(data, fpl1(d1+asymp.RNoiseByIndividual1[Individual], d2+asymp.RNoiseByIndividual2[Individual], d3+asymp.RNoiseByIndividual3[Individual], Day)+rnorm(nrow(data),mean=0,sd=residualSD))
  data
}


totalDaysMeasured <- 25
delta1 <- 5.051236
delta2 <- 13.86703
delta3 <- 0.8486555

data2Groups <- createDataset(1,totalDaysMeasured, delta1, delta2, delta3)
ggplot(data2Groups,aes(x=Day,y=X,colour=Group))+geom_point()


initialValues2Groups <-  c( delta1=delta1,
                            delta2=delta2,
                            delta3=delta3)

nparams <- c("A","C","D")
fpl <- deriv(as.formula(paste0("~(A*exp(x-C))/(1+exp((x-C)/D))")),
             nparams,
             function.arg=c("x",nparams),
             envir=environment())
attr(fpl,"pnames") <- nparams

tmpstr <- deparse(fpl)
L1 <- grep("^ +\\.value +<-",tmpstr)
L2 <- grep("^ +attr\\(\\.value",tmpstr)
hej <- deparse(nparams)[1]
tmpstr2 <- c(tmpstr[1:L1],
             paste0(".actualArgs <- as.list(match.call()[",
                    hej,"])"),
             tmpstr[(L1+1):(L2-1)],
             "dimnames(.grad) <- list(NULL, .actualArgs)",
             tmpstr[L2:length(tmpstr)])
fpl <- eval(parse(text=tmpstr2),envir = environment())
nlmerString <- paste0("X ~ fpl(delta1, delta2, delta3, Day) ~ (delta1|Individual)+(delta3|Individual)+(delta3|Individual)")
startTimeNLMER <- Sys.time()
nlmerFit <- do.call("nlmer",list(
  as.formula(nlmerString),
  start=initialValues2Groups,
  data=data2Groups, 
  control = nlmerControl(optimizer = "Nelder_Mead", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000)
  )))

endTimeNLMER <- Sys.time()
#print(paste0("Time required for the ",deparse(substitute(data)),": ",endTimeNLMER-startTimeNLMER))
#nlmerFit
```

Anyone got any solutions to this problem?

I have also tried:

```
    library("R.utils")

# Packages
library(parallel)
library(nlme)
library(ggplot2)
library(Matrix)
library(MASS)
library(nlraa)
library(lme4)


# Initial settings
num_subjects <- 600
num_time_points <- 25
n_sim <- 1000
N_T = num_subjects * num_time_points

# Define fixed effects
delta1 <- 5.051236
delta2 <- 13.86703
delta3 <- 0.8486555
initial_params <- c(delta1 = 5.051236, delta2 = 13.86703, delta3 = 0.8486555)

# Define the upper triangular matrix for the covariance matrix D
D <- rbind(c(51.88633, -1.0498620, -0.05460614), c(-1.0498620, 15.8465000, -0.04587260), c(-0.05460614, -0.04587260, 0.01362791))


# Parallel ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Model function
nparams <- c("delta1", "delta2", "delta3", "eta1i", "eta2i","eta3i", "Time")
fpl <- deriv(as.formula(paste0("~((delta1+eta1i) * exp(Time - (delta2+eta2i) )) / (1 + exp((Time - (delta2+eta2i)) / (delta3+eta3i)))")), c("eta1i", "eta2i","eta3i"), function.arg = nparams, envir=environment())


nlmerString <- paste0("value ~ fpl(delta1, delta2, delta3, eta1i, eta2i,eta3i, Time) ~ (eta1i|Subject)+(eta2i|Subject)+(eta3i|Subject)")

random_effects <- mvrnorm(n = num_subjects, mu = rep(0, 3), Sigma = D)
eps <- c()

# Create an empty list to store the data
data_list <- list()

# Generate data for each subject
for (subject_id in 1:num_subjects) {
  # Get the random effects for the subject
  eta1i <- random_effects[subject_id, 1]
  eta2i <- random_effects[subject_id, 2]
  eta3i <- random_effects[subject_id, 3]
  eps_i <- rnorm(num_time_points, mean = 0, sd = 0.939921)
  eps <- append(eps, eps_i)
  
  # Create a data frame for the subject
  subject_data <- data.frame(
    Subject = factor(subject_id),
    Time = seq(0, 25, length.out = num_time_points),
    eps = eps_i,
    eta1i = eta1i,
    eta2i = eta2i,
    eta3i = eta3i
  )
  
  # Calculate delta values for the subject
  delta1i <- delta1 + eta1i
  delta2i <- delta2 + eta2i
  delta3i <- delta3 + eta3i
  
  # Generate data based on the specified model
  subject_data$value <- with(subject_data, (delta1i * exp(Time - delta2i)) / (1 + exp((Time - delta2i) / delta3i)) + eps_i)
  
  # Add the subject's data to the list
  data_list[[subject_id]] <- subject_data
}

simulated_data_normal <- do.call("rbind", data_list)

nlmerFit <- do.call("nlmer",list(
  as.formula(nlmerString),
  start = initial_params,
  data=simulated_data_normal)
)
```

Where I instead gets

```
Error: step factor reduced below 0.001 without reducing pwrss
```

Where I get the other error if I try and debug it and "jump over" the line that gives this error.

I have tried removing two of the random effects to make the model more simple, changing the staring values multiple times, tried other optimizers in "nlmerControl". Furthermore, when I try fitting the non-linear mixed model with nlme::nlme, it works fine. However, I would like to compare the results of the two functions.

Comment: This doesn't actually solve your problem, but the parameters of `fpl1` and `fpl` are not in the same order (as written, `fpl` should take `Day` as its *first* argument for the formula to match). Also, the meaning of the two errors is essentially '(quasi)complete separation exists' and 'sub-optimal starting values' respectively.

Comment: Thanks, i fixed it and now I just get the "step factor" error in both examples. But now it at least makes a little more sense, since it is the same error when doing the "same" thing.

Comment: Another guess is that your random effects are *way* too big, have you tried overplotting your theoretical fitting line onto the raw data? The model seems to run OK if you reduce your random effects by say, 100-fold.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by reducing the random effects by a 100-fold, can you elaborate?
I have tried to reduce nIndividuals/num_subjects to 6, and it then seem to converge 50% of the times I simulate/fit the data/model, but I would like to include 600 not 6

Comment: The values of `D`/`random_effects` are enormous compared to the fixed effects, as a result you are essentially trying to fit a line through a set of points that fans out exponentially in both directions; like [this](https://i.imgur.com/IOs2WBX.png). If you reduce the magnitude of the random effects significantly you get something like [this](https://i.imgur.com/NvguxZu.png), which seems much more like a model that will actually *fit* your data.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the problem. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @PBulls, please post as answer?

Answer (score 2):

Summarizing the comments discussion:

- Your `fpl1` data-generating and `fpl` modelling functions do not accept their arguments in the same order, `fpl` takes `Day` as *first* argument.
- The random effects are **so** large that they dwarf any fixed effect in your model.

Expanding on the latter - you didn't seed your simulation but a representative dataset might look like this scatterplot of observations with the fixed-effect trend as a red line:
[image: raw data scatterplot]

Clearly, even the fixed part of your *data-generating* model is a pretty poor fit! If you were to scale down `D` or `random_effects` by an order of magnitude or two you get something like this, where your model actually has a chance of fitting the data:
[image: raw data scatterplot with reduced random variance]

Finally, summarizing the usual source of these errors: `Downdated VtV is not positive definite` suggests [(quasi)complete separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_(statistics)), and `step factor reduced below 0.001 without reducing pwrss` points to starting values being too far from optimal for the model to proceed.